# Rails, mapbox and geocoder : find object near another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mapbox, rails-geocoder

I try to find an object @center near an object @school depending the location, and show the center on mapbox. I past my code here because I'm not sure of what I did :

here is the code displaying map (with 2 data : school and center) :

```
<div id="school-map" data-coordinates="<%= @school.coordinates.reverse %>" data-centers="<%= @center.coordinates.reverse %>"> </div>
```

here is the center.rb model :

```
class Center
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Geocoder::Model::Mongoid

  has_many :schools
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :schools

  field :title,             type: String

  field :image_path,        type: String
  field :Attachment_path,   type: String
  field :website,           type: String

  field :phone,             type: String

  field :street,            type: String
  field :zipcode,           type: String
  field :city,              type: String
  field :coordinates,       type: Array

  geocoded_by :adress
  #after_validation :geocode

  def adress
    [street, zipcode, city].compact.joint(', ')
  end

end
```

In school.rb model, I try this method :

```
   def center_near_school(school_adress_coordinates)
school_adress_coordinates = @school.coordinates.reverse
center = Center.near(school_adress_coordinates, 1, units: :km)
```

end

and I try to show string like "yes" or "no" to know if my method work :

```
<% if @school.center_near_school %>
            <p> OUI </p>
          <% else %>
            <p> NON </p>
          <% end %>
```

I create relation (has_many :schools, and has_many :centers) in both models, the markers generations are created in show.js which displaying the map.

Does someone could help me to find some solutions to create this functionality ?

Don't hesitate to ask me to edit this post with more informations (code, precisions ...)

thank !

Comment: `join`, not `joint`. What works already? Is `near` a method you'd like to write?

Comment: @EricDuminil the method near is a geocoder method that already exist

Comment: So. What works, what doesn't? Do you get any error?

Comment: Nothing work for now, Because I'm a bit lost, I try some things but I haven't any results, and the errors that append are logics, I just want to have some indications because I'm lost : how to proceed ?

Comment: @EricDuminil I update my post, with the new method I tried, and I have this following error : `undefined method `center_near_school' for #<School:0x007fa360097aa8>`

Comment: `@school` is a model, so `center_near_school` should be defined in `School` model, not in a controller.

Comment: This is probaly not related but `field :Attachment_path` should be in snakecase `field :attachment_path`. Never use uppercase in identifiers and field names in Ruby unless it is a CONSTANT or ClassName.

Comment: @EricDuminil, I put the method in school model, but I have the same issue, I have updated my post again

Comment: In the `School` model, `@school.coordinates` should be `self.coordinates` or just `coordinates`

Comment: @EricDuminil ok I haven't any errors, but i have the string "OUI" instead it should be write "NON" because I haven't any centers near this school

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Center.near(school_adress_coordinates, 1, units: :km)`

returns an Array of Centers, which can be empty if no Center is found.

Your method should be called `centers_near_school`, and you could use :

```
<% if @school.centers_near_school.empty? %>
  <p> NON </p>
<% else %>
  <p> OUI </p>
<% end %>
```

In Ruby, every object is "truthy", except `false` and `nil`. Even an empty Array is considered to be true in an if statement.